gradle: create IntelliJ run configurations programmatically?
The gradle-idea-ext-plugin provides a nice DSL to generate runConfigurations.
I want to create a lot of them which differ in jvmArgs only.
Currently I have to repeat the whole block of parameter again and again.
It there any way to define a simple factory method to create them?
Or copy and configure some template configuration?
